# Using std::find with a custom Book class

Tags: c++, algorithm, stdvector

Here is my main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include "Book.h"

using namespace std;

vector<Book> removeDuplicates(vector<Book> oldbookvector)
{
    vector<Book> newbookvector;
    vector<string> booknames;

    for(vector<Book>::size_type i = 0; i < oldbookvector.size(); i ++){
        booknames.push_back(oldbookvector[i].bookname());
    }

    vector<Book>::iterator it;
    for(vector<Book>::size_type i = 0; i < oldbookvector.size(); i ++){
        //If it find a value then it returns the first element
        it = find(newbookvector.begin(),newbookvector.end(), oldbookvector[i]);
        if(it == newbookvector.end()){
            booknames.push_back(oldbookvector[i].bookname());
        }
    }

    return newbookvector;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    vector<Book> books;
    vector<Book> newbooks;

    books.push_back(Book("The C Programming Language", 1980));
    books.push_back(Book("Javascript: The Good Parts", 2008));
    books.push_back(Book("Accelerated C++: Pratical Programming by Example", 2000));
    books.push_back(Book("Scala for the Impatient", 2012));
    books.push_back(Book("The C Programming Language", 1980));
    books.push_back(Book("Javascript: The Good Parts", 2008));
    books.push_back(Book("Accelerated C++: Pratical Programming by Example", 2000));
    books.push_back(Book("Scala for the Impatient", 2012));

    cout << &books[2] << endl;
    cout << books[2].bookname() << endl;

    //Test to make sure book class was working
    Book stuff = Book("The Book about stuff", 1998);
    cout << stuff.bookname() << endl;
    cout << stuff.bookyear() << endl;

    stuff.printBook();

    //newbooks = removeDuplicates(books);

    //Print out the vector without duplicates
    for(vector<Book>::size_type i = 0; i < newbooks.size(); i ++){
        cout << newbooks[i].bookname() << newbooks[i].bookyear() << "\t";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting an error in algorithm.cc that says "Invalid operands to binary expression ('Book' and 'const Book')". I think it is coming from the find(). Im pretty sure the problem is the iterator is not iterating  through the books

Here is my Book class

```
#ifndef Question2_Book_h
#define Question2_Book_h
using namespace std;

class Book{
public:
    Book();

    Book(string n, int y){
        name = n;
        year = y;
    }

    string bookname(){
        return name;
    }
    int bookyear(){
        return year;
    }

    void printBook(){
        cout << name << ", " << year << endl;
    }

private:
    string name;
    int year;
};
#endif
```

Comment: Please copy and paste the *exact* error message. You most likely skip over important details when you try to paraphrase.

Comment: @Code-Guru: He *did* enter the exact error message (`"Invalid operands to binary expression ('Book' and 'const Book')"`), and it's simple enough.  The same error would occur if you wrote `bool b = Book() == Book();`

Answer (score 1):

- `std::find` is located in the `<algorithm>` so first you should be including that header.
- In order to find a `Book`, you need to define the `operator==` (`std::find` uses it to determine whether a `Book` was found), otherwise how would you know if you found a `Book` or not?

**Example**

```
bool operator==(const Book& b1, const Book& b2)
{
    // 2 books are equal if they have the same name, you could also compare years
    // if you want
    return b1.bookname() == b2.bookname();
}
```

Also, note that I am using `const`. In order to use the above, you would need to fix one part of your code (notice I added a `const`):

```
string bookname() const {
     return name;
}
```